# iphone: select and copy subset of items from a master array of dictionary items into a temporary array of dictionaries

Tags: iphone, arrays, core-data, dictionary

I have an array of dictionary items containing a list of menus and their country of origin.  Any number of menus may come from any country.  I need an efficient way to select a country and then extract all the items from the first array of dictionaries that pertain to that country.  I'm wanting to create a temporary array of dictionaries that contain all the menu and related data for the chosen country.

To be clear.  I do not want something like `NSArray *extracted = [sourceArray valueForKey:@"country"];` as this will only create an array of countries.  I want to chose, e.g. Italy and pull back the full Item for each dictionary where Country == Italy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country == %@", @"Italy"];
NSArray *result = [sourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```